# How to search by image on my computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, search, photos

In a similar way to Google's [search by image](https://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ei=3hepVd-qNsf_ugSE2pyoBA&ved=0CBIQqi4oAQ), I want to search on my PC. I have a similar photo with me, but not the exact one. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this after googling a bit: [Visual Similarity Duplicate Image Finder](http://download.cnet.com/Visual-Similarity-Duplicate-Image-Finder/3000-2193_4-10422191.html)

Original discussion was [here](http://www.ultimatecarpage.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41918).